# Slice by condition List R

Tags: r, list

I'm working on a list of dataframes and I need to slice by the maximum value of one column.

```
df1 = data.frame(Year = c(2010,2011,2012),  Var_1= c(1,3,3))
df2 = data.frame(Year = c(2010,2011,2012), Var_2 = c(4,3,5))
l = list(df1, df2)
```

How can I slice for the maximum value of the year column in R?

Regards,

Comment: Try `lapply(l, function(x) x[which.max(x[,2]),])`.

Comment: Great comment! How to keep max rows in the case the maximum values appears more than once?

Comment: If you want `2011, 2012` in `df1`, try `lapply(l, function(x) x[x[,2] == max(x[,2]),])`.